# Simply update ACF field value via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, acfpro

I’m trying to update an ACF field value in the database via jQuery. This is super simple to via PHP, using `update_field()`, however i cant go with this approach as I want to make the update based on the current time in a html5 video. That part is not really relevant, as I’m just after a simple way to update the field value via jQuery. Surely this must be quite straight forward, but can’t find anything in the JavaScript ACF docs?

Thanks

Comment: You can use AJAX to run PHP code "in the background". Establish a suitable endpoint, write the PHP code you want to run, then request the endpoint URL from your JS code using `fetch()` or `$.get()`

Comment: Hi Chris, I was thinking along these lines but just seems quite complex to me, given that they have a full JS API? Would you be able to shed a bit more light via an answer? Thanks

Comment: Assuming that `update_field()` writes to the database, there's no way to do this with just JavaScript, since JS doesn't run on the server but inside the user's browser. It has no direct database access. Client-side JS isn't an alternative to PHP in any sense, so whatever the JS API does, it's not the same as what the PHP API does.

Comment: Thanks Chris that’s a helpful explanation, makes sense. Will attempt an Ajax/PHP solution tomorrow